# Centrifugo real-time server

Tags: comet

Работаю с сервером centrifugo, вызываю метод channels что бы посмотреть каналы, потом вызываю метод presence и передаю в него канал, но вместо данных о пользователях канала получаю ошибку error 108 not available, хотя указываю существующий канал. В чем проблема?

Comment: а к каналу в этот момент кто-нибудь подключен? centrifugo закрывает канал , если в нем никого нет (вроде как...)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел свою ошибку, нужно было в файле конфигурации (config.json) указать "presence": true.

P.S. Лучше читать документацию внимательно.